# How do I refer to the _id field in a mongodb database via a REST API GET call?

Tags: mongodb, rest, nestjs

This is hard to explain, so please bear with me.

I have a Nestjs-based server that is using MongoDB as the back end.  Here are the three entries from the mongodb collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e87ef7a9cf8648fac6b9f1e"},"complete":false,"editMode":false,"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1585966970857"}},"createdBy":"user","isDeleted":false,"title":"Make a birthday cake","note":"Make sure she poops."}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e87f081237c70a6782d6c2a"},"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1585967233825"}},"createdBy":"user","isDeleted":false,"complete":false,"editMode":false,"title":"Clean the kitchen","note":"Use Lysol"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e87f73be81d7e0061311187"},"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1585968955971"}},"createdBy":"user","isDeleted":false,"complete":false,"editMode":false,"title":"Walk the dog","note":"Make sure she poops."}
```

Here is my model:

```
@Entity()
export class Todo {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  @Transform(value => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })
  id: ObjectID;

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  title: string;

  @Column({ length: 5000 })
  note: string;

  @Column()
  complete: boolean;

  @Column()
  editMode: boolean;

  @Exclude() @Column() createdAt: Date = new Date();
  @Exclude() @Column() createdBy: string = 'user';
  @Exclude() @Column() isDeleted: boolean = false;
}
```

Here is my GET-er stuff:

```
  @Get(':id')
  async getTodo(@Param('id') id: number) {
    return this.todosService.getTodo(id);
  }


  async getTodo(id: number): Promise<Todo | undefined> {
    return this.todosRepository.findOne(id, {
      where: {
        isDeleted: false,
      },
    });
  }
```

I would like to run a REST GET call to retrieve one of the documents, say the third one.  Therefore I call in my browser:

http://localhost:3000/todos/5e87f73be81d7e0061311187

Well, this returns the first document.  In fact, anything I call only returns the first document.

What should my GET call be to get the third item?

I can provide any further information that might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, i think the id parameter (id: number), should be a string. 
Also, findone takes all the querying parameter in first argument itself ( atleast in JS), so it should be like todoRepository.findOne({_id .$oid: string, isDeleted: false }).
Can you tell me what's $oid? ObjectId type? I haven't worked with nest.js/ typescript. Depending upon this you might want to improve the $oid in query argument.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  ObjectID is the key added by MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:  Make the `id` parameter an `ObjectID` type everywhere in the application.

For instance:

```
 @Get(':id')
  async getTodo(@Param('id') id: ObjectID) {
    return this.todosService.getTodo(id);
  }


  async getTodo(id: ObjectID): Promise<Todo | undefined> {
    return this.todosRepository.findOne(id, {
      where: {
        isDeleted: false,
      },
    });
  }
```

Once I did that, it all worked as expected.